# Error using SUM for multiple columns in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Below is the input data for Pig which is unstructured

```
file1.txt
---------
input|key1|id1|1|1|2|3
input|key1|id1|1|0|1
input|key1|id1|1|1
```

The expected output is single record where first 3 column values are same for all records, and I need to sum up the 4th & 5th column.

```
key1|id1|3|2
```

Below is the error:

```
data = load 'file1.txt' using PigStorage('|');
temp1 = foreach data generate $1,$2,sum($3),sum($4);
```

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve
>   sum using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin.,
>   org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Answer (score 1):

You need to `group` the data and then use a SUM. Also, SUM will be capital and that's what your error is about.

```
data = load 'file.txt' using PigStorage('|');
grouped = GROUP data by ($0, $1, $2);
result = FOREACH grouped generate FlATTEN(group), SUM((int)$3), SUM((int)$4);
DUMP result;
```

Comment: My data is unstructured, updated my post. I can't define schema.

Comment: @useriw Dont define the schema then.

Comment: Failed while executing the below statement. grunt> result = FOREACH grouped generate FlATTEN(group), SUM((int)$3), SUM((int)$4);
2017-05-24 10:05:44,454 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: 
<line 3, column 59> Out of bound access. Trying to access non-existent column: 3. Schema group:tuple(:bytearray,:bytearray,:bytearray),data:bag{:tuple()} has 2 column(s).